# 'Connection reset' receiving data over socket in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have to send and Receive data over the WiFi within two android device.
Code is working fine when I connect the android server code.

Problem is that when i send acknowledgement from server to client it gives exception at client side.
I have to Send data from client to server and after that It should return the acknowledgement to Client.

```
   W: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
W:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:592)
W:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)
W:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
W:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
W:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
W:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
W:     at in.co.prosimerp.serverdemo.CleintActivity$MyClientTask.doInBackground(CleintActivity.java:103)
W:     at in.co.prosimerp.serverdemo.CleintActivity$MyClientTask.doInBackground(CleintActivity.java:67)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
W:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
W:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:185)
W:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
W:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
```

Client code :

```
    socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                             OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
               String number = "2";
               String sendMessage = number + "\n";
                bw.write(sendMessage);
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
               InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
//Exception at this point
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }
```

Sever Code :

```
 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                count++;
                message += "A#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                        + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";                 

                OutputStream outputStream;
                String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + count;

                try {
                    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                    printStream.print(msgReply);
                    printStream.close();

                    message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            msg.setText(message);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
                }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got Answer

Using available() is the only way to do it without resorting to asynchronous methods.

```
 while(nis.available()>0){
                        int i=nis.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                        if(i<0)break;
                        System.out.print("bytes"+new String(buffer, 0, i));
                    }
```

Comment: The only way to do what?

Comment: To Send and receive data over the sockets.

Comment: Well you're wrong, it isn't the ionly way, and it isn't even the best way. You don't need it. Just read until you get end of stream. `available()` doesn't even solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is sending a message that is never read by the server. When the server closes the socket with unread pending data, it causes a connection reset instead of a normal close.

Comment: Yes i m not reading that data at server side R8 now. I have to read Acknowledgement at client side.

Comment: No. You're already reading at the client side. What's missing is the server-side read.

Comment: Actually i am getting the exception at client side while reading data using inputStream.

Comment: Actually you are getting the exception at the client because the client sent something that the server didn't read, and instead closed the connection, which caused the connection reset, as already stated in my answer. The solution to the problem is a read at the server, obviously. Instead of just mindlessly arguing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.This code is working for me. nis and nos are Input and Output Streams.

```
private class SocketserverThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {

            while (true) {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(socketServerPORT));
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                nis = socket.getInputStream();
                nos = socket.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes;
                bytes = nis.read(buffer);
                if (bytes != -1) {
                    readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
          if (readMessage.length() != 0 || readMessage != "null") {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                nis.close();
                socket.close();
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have to send result back to the client also.

Comment: And mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.

Comment: Put this code in oncreate method. So that the problem may be resolved.                                          if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }